# Add a "Presentations and Talks" section

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It would be great to have a section in Careers.SO profiles, to list talks and presentations that a user  has done.

My local community (Philadelphia) has a huge amount of tech talks and presentations in the city, and I've been privileged enough to have presented on a few topics. I'd like to show them off in my Careers profile.

Comment: Off topic: I'm recently back in Philadelphia, is there an authoritative list of this kind of thing?

Comment: @agf - Most of the groups are on Meetup. Check out PhillyDB, Philly Python UserGroup (PUG), and also Philly Linux User's group (phillylinux.org)

Answer (score 1):

Feels kind of strange with the proliferation of meetups (at least in Europe, can't speak for anywhere else) that with the lower barrier of giving talks / presentations this would be a fundamental piece of profile information :)

(taking meetup.com / joind.in / tex(x) / etc into account here and thinking of possible API connections to those sites the same way the projects section of a profile can be linked to github / bitbucket etc)

Answer (score 0):

Another two services that can be linked to are [SlideShare.com](http://slideshare.com) and [Slides.com](http://slides.com)

This section is a MUST! How hasn't this feature/section been created yet?

C'mon StackExchange, let's do this! :)